# Trying to send message to a specific channel with a discord bot using Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

As mentioned in the title I am trying to send a message to a specific channel using a discord bot that I've built using Discord.js and Node.js. I am using the following code to send the message to the specific channel: `message.guild.channels.cache.find('CHANNEL_ID').send(someEmbed);`. The problem is, whenever I add this piece of code to the file and run it, I get an error message in the console. The error is message is the following: `if (fn(val, key, this)) TypeError: fn is not a function`, this error message refers to a file that is automatically generated. So my question is if I'm doing something wrong or if it's some sort of bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try

```js
message.guild.channels.cache.get("CHANNEL_ID").send(someEmbed);
```

although your code should run without any problems.

Comment: This runs great now, no error messages anymore, thanks for the help!